# How to get the user's location using GPS

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have an activity in which I have a text view where I want to display the distance between the user's current location and a specific address. I have the Latitude and Logitude of the address but my issue is getting the user's location. My target is when the activity is created that's when I want to get his location' without pressing any button. I have tried multiple ways: getLastKnownLocation, onLocation changed etc, but the value returned is always null.

It's important to note that I am running the app on an emulator.

Sample code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_list);

        Bundle bundleUser = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String owneruser = bundleUser.getString("username");

        Bundle bundleType = getIntent().getExtras();
        String type = bundleType.getString("type");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                t.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " + location.getLatitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        final Location userLocation = new Location("");
        userLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        userLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
}

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                update();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void update(){
        // first check for permissions
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                        ,10);
            }
        }
        else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listener);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement your activity to LocationListener :

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
 private Location userLocation = new Location("");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}

      @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location != null){
        userLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        userLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

TRY this to grant permission:

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, RC_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the result of the request.
        }
    }
```

and add this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: by this without pressing any buttons any time that location changes, you can get the location

Comment: Says I have to implement the abstract method onProviderEnabled which I have

Comment: Also where are you getting the location here? Could you possibly add that to your code please?

Comment: @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null){
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

Comment: I have a problem with the "implements LocationListener" it says I have to implement onProviderEnabled but I already did...

Comment: Ok the problem is fixed now, my question is how to do I put the location in my userLocation variable? If you look at my code I have declared on Location userLocation in my on create method, that's where I want to put the user's location, how do I do that?

Comment: just set the lat and long you got in onLocation changes

Comment: can you please add that to your code? It doesn't seem to be working for me so it would help if I can see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146580/discussion-between-meikiem-and-jokerah).

Comment: But when is onLocationChanged called? How do I call it from the oncreate function